# NSString value not same across method calls?

Tags: objective-c

I have an Objective-C method that formats a `double` to a currency `NSString`:

```
- (NSString*) formatCurrencyValue:(double)value
{
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehaviorDefault];
    [numberFormatter setCurrencySymbol:@"$"];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSNumber *c = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:value];

    NSString* stringValue = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:c];

    NSLog(@"currencyFormatter=%@",stringValue);

    return stringValue;
}
```

The `NSLog` statement correctly prints the formatted double.  However, when I call this method and assign it another `NSString` object, its value is empty.

For example:

```
NSString* key = [self formatCurrencyValue:menuItem.Price];

NSLog(@"Key value=", key);
```

The output from the `NSLog` statement there is:

> Key value=

What's going on???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `NSLog(@"Key value=", key);`, you're missing the `%@` placeholder that tells Objective-C where to print the argument.

It should be `NSLog(@"Key value=%@", key);`.

Comment: @Wayne: You're welcome.  You would think that the compiler would warn you when you passed in too many arguments vs. format specifiers, but I remember reading somewhere that there's a specific reason this isn't done in Objective-C...